# moment timezone not giving right output

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

Need your help to solve this moment.js timezone library.

I am running below code and both gives me same output. but i am expecting different with provided timezone.

```
moment.tz('2013-12-01 03:00:00', "Asia/Kolkata").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS');
"2013-12-01 03:00:00"

moment.tz('2013-12-01 03:00:00', "America/Los_Angeles").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS');
"2013-12-01 03:00:00"
```

Am i doing anything wrong here? Because i want to use it in my entire php application.

```
moment.tz.setDefault("America/Los_Angeles");
moment('2013-12-01 03:00:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS'); 
> "2013-12-01 03:00:00" 

moment.tz.setDefault("Asia/Kolkata"); 
moment('2013-12-01 03:00:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS'); 
>"2013-12-01 03:00:00"
```

As well above code gives same output. it will not expected as well.

Comment: You haven't described what you are trying to do.  For example, are you trying to convert from one time zone to the other?  Which is the source and which is the destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs - the right way to achieve this is following

```
moment('2013-12-01 03:00:00').tz("Asia/Kolkata").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS');
moment('2013-12-01 03:00:00').tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS');
```

Comment: Yes. You are right.
But again if i use setDefault to set globally timezone for whole application, then again it give same date like below.

moment.tz.setDefault("America/Los_Angeles");
moment('2013-12-01 03:00:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS');
> "2013-12-01 03:00:00"

moment.tz.setDefault("Asia/Kolkata");
moment('2013-12-01 03:00:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS');
>"2013-12-01 03:00:00"

Comment: And what behaviour are you expecting? You've set default TZ and created moment object with specific time and date. It's been created with TZ you've set as default. Time formatted won't be changed